# SharePoint 2010 and MVC using same STS fails when SharePoint logged in first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint

I have a custom STS built using the template from Visual Studio. It works great when I just use it in SharePoint or just in MVC. But if I log into SharePoint first, I get the following message when I log into the MVC site.

ID4230: The SecurityToken was not well formed. Expecting element name 'SecurityContextToken', found 'SP'.

It seems like SharePoint is modifying the Federated cookie and causing it to only work in SharePoint sites.

Has anyone seen this issue before? I would seem that Microsoft has planned to allow SharePoint and other .NET applications to live together.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Hate to answer my own question. But the issue I was having was that the SharePoint site A was dev.sites.com and the MVC was books.dev.sites.com. The STS federated cookie was using the cookie issues from dev.sites.com and ignoring the fact that book existed in the domain. Might be a bug in the STS to allow for multiple levels of authentication when the site you logged into was the lower on the domains.

Log into dev.sites.com first

```
tapes.sites.com fine
this.sites.com fine
books.dev.sites.com FAIL
```