# Putting SharePoint and .NET into a shared claims provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a custom STS up and running and it works great for all my SharePoint sites. I have single sign on working across all the SharePoint sites. It also works fine for my .NET MVC site. But if I log into my MVC site and navigate to SharePoint, SharePoint sends me to the STS to log in again.

How can I tell SharePoint to trust the Federated cookie from the MVC site login?

I thought about adding the MVC site to the realms list, but there is no /_trust/ page in the MVC site. So I would assume  that the realms list in SharePoint is only for SharePoint sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298404/sharepoint-2010-and-mvc-using-same-sts-fails-when-sharepoint-logged-in-first) has the same answer as this. The STS has issue with sites with multiple domain levels when you log into a site with the lower domain level.

```
dev.sites.com log into
tapes.sites.com works fine
books.dev.sites.com FAILS.
```

More detailed answer here in my other post.
[SharePoint 2010 and MVC using same STS fails when SharePoint logged in first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298404/sharepoint-2010-and-mvc-using-same-sts-fails-when-sharepoint-logged-in-first)